# Unable to handle null pointers in Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, kernel

Hello currently I don't know why I can't check the pointer whether it is NULL or not. 
I am trying to check whether task->signal->tty->name has a name or NULL but it actually identifies itself as a NULL even if it has a name.

I have used the simple iterating function 
suggestions? regarding to this issue?

Comment: What do you think, the first part of your condition will evaluate to? And then what will be overall result of the expression?

Comment: what your code says is "if tty_name != NULL or if tty_name == NULL". this makes no sense

Comment: `if (tty_name || tty_name == NULL)` is equivalent to `if (tty_name != NULL || tty_name == NULL)`. Any more questions?

Comment: I have fixed the operands as told but it does not change the fact that I cannot handle NULL value, or is there something I have missed?

Comment: What did you fix? Did you understand what Michael wrote? You should remove the first part of the condition. What you do is `if ( x!=0 || x == 0)` which is **always** `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try it like this:

```
for_each_process(task) {
  char *tty_name = NULL;
  if (task && task->signal && task->signal->tty)
    tty_name = task->signal->tty->name; 

  if (tty_name == NULL) {
    // Handle NULL pointer  
  } else {
    // Handle valid pointers
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much... I've been hammering this without sleeping.

Answer (score -1):

The condition expression for handling null pointer should be like this:

if(!tty_name || tty_name == NULL)

Comment: Yes. I have tried that but still it considers itself as a value even if it is NULL

Comment: Why should anyone include `!tty_name` into the condition?